# Obtener varias propiedades del objeto

Tags: c#, poo

Hola me gustaría saber qué soluciones hay para reducir un objeto. Ósea tengo un modelo el cual se utiliza como retorno en el controlador pero solo me interesan ciertas propiedades de ese modelo. La idea principal que se me ocurrió fue crear un objeto anónimo solo con esas propiedades, pero me gustaría saber que opciones tengo.

```
namespace aplication {
    class UserModel{
        public string Car{ get; set; }
        public string Dir { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}

public ActionResult Login() {
            UserModel user = new UserModel();
            //nuevo objeto con las propiedades Name y email
            return View(nuevoObjeto);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que se suele hacer en estos casos es utilizar un modelo de vista (o view model): una clase creada específicamente para utilizarla como modelo en la vista:

```
class LoginViewModel{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Login() {
    var user = new UserModel();
    // Código en el que cargas las propiedades de user
    var model = new LoginViewModel() { Name = user.Name, Email = user.Email };
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Gracias, este modelo por eso tiene que salir de UserModel

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que quieres decir

Comment: me refiero que tengo que sacar el UserViewModel de UserModel user = new UserModel();

Comment: He editado la respuesta. He cambiado el nombre del modelo de vista por LoginViewModel (que creo que es más claro) e inicializo los valores del modelo de vista a partir de un objeto UserModel.

Comment: Y otra pregunta simple en el modelo se puede introducir lógica? o solo tiene las propiedades de un objeto?

Comment: Sí, claro. En el modelo MVC son las clases que definen el Modelo las que tienen la lógica de negocio. Si utiliza modelos y modelos de vista (lo que se denomina un modelo MMVC) las clases del Modelo tendrán la lógica de negocio, mientras que las de Modelos de Vista prácticamente no tendrán código, sólo la necesaria para adaptar los datos a las necesidades de la vista o atributos de DataAnnotations para la presentación de los datos.

Comment: Entonces finalmente si mi objeto le llega de otro proyecto, de todas las formas sera necesario crear un objeto Model en la carpeta models para utilizarlo a la vista?

Comment: No necesariamente. Si la clase definida en tu capa de negocio se ajusta a las necesidades de la vista puedes utilizarla como modelo. Pero en la mayoría de los casos comprobarás que no es así, que no necesitas toda la información (como en el caso que comentas) o que necesitas enviar a la vista más información de la que te proporciona un único objeto de la capa de negocio. En estos casos (ya te digo que serán la mayoría) es conveniente crearse un modelo de vista en la carpeta Models en lugar de utilizar otros sistemas (como enviar información con el ViewBag, por ejemplo).

Comment: Es que realmente lo que me pasa es que solo tengo que pasar una propiedad a la vista que esta viene del objeto UserModel(de otro proyecto) y me gustaria que fuese fuertemente tipada, la única opción seria crear un objeto(vistamodelo) con una sola propiedad para pasarlo a la vista?

Comment: No, si únicamente tienes que pasar un valor puedes pasárselo directamente. Es decir, si el valor es por ejemplo de tipo string, puedes pasárselo a la vista y en ésta definir que el tipo de datos del modelo es string: @model String